# Follow pattern at an angle with router?

Tags: technique, router

I'm currently building a set of templates for an Adirondack chair, and have come across a problem that will jump out once I start to use the patterns.

For the back of the chair, the rail needs to be cut at a 6° angle, so that it matches the angle that the rear of the chair is at. How would I set up the router so that I can get this angle correct?

I'm trying to do as much with the router and patterns as I can, because if I use the band saw, I'd have a variance in the final cuts - I want to be as consistent as possible.

Comment: Normally you would either make that cut on a table saw/bandsaw, or cut it to length by pattern and then make the angle vis sanding, planing, or some similar second process.

Comment: It is not clear to me which parts you are discussing.  A picture.sketch with an arrow would help.

Comment: Completely OT: I replaced `6degree` with `6°` 'cause it looks fancier! On Windows, hold the Alt-Key down, then type `248` on the _numeric keypad_ (it won't work if you use the numbers above the letters). There are similar methods for Mac and *nix, I'm sure. Google `alt key codes` for listings of all the codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many (most?) adirondack chair designs have flat backs rather than curved backs, making the cuts for that back bar relatively simple since it is just a bevel cut across the edge of a straight board.

Since you mentioned wanting to use a router at an angle, you can get tilt bases for most compact/trim routers. Since you're only talking a few degrees, you could also make a slanted base for a larger router, but if you needed to tilt significantly (e.g., 30 or 45 degrees) the broader base of the larger router would interfere and you would need a much longer bit in order to make the same cut.

Here are a few additional options:

1. Table saw with the blade tilted
2. Router table with angled auxiliary tabletop
3. Jointer with fence tilted
4. Bandsaw with table tilted
5. Hand plane

Comment: Thanks Rob. The design I'm working to has a curved back, but a slanted base for a router sounds like a possibility. I could use a curved spokeshave, a good plan B, but I'm trying to reduce the possibility of differences.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If you do use a spokeshave, you may find a flat one easier to handle for long, sweeping curves, although a curved spokeshave is necessary for tighter curves.

Comment: Rob: I have both, but I've always understood it as rounded for inside curves, flat for outside curves. I'll try both - that way I get to try out twice as many cuss words! :)

Comment: A bevel-cutting bit would also be a possibility, though I'm not sure what's available at 6 degrees.

Comment: Yes, that is another option--for example, if you can find a large enough dovetail bit, you may be able to reshape the cutters slightly to make a 6 degree cut.